# json array com serialize javascript não funcionando

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho esse formulário:

```
<form>
        <select name="data">
            <option>0831</option>
            <option selected>4731</option>
            <option>9831</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="telefone[0].numero" placeholder="Telefone"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="telefone[0].operadora" placeholder="Telefone"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="telefone[0].contato" placeholder="Telefone"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="telefone[1].numero" placeholder="Telefone"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="telefone[1].operadora" placeholder="Telefone"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="telefone[1].contato" placeholder="Telefone"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="endereco[]" placeholder="Endereço"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="endereco[]" placeholder="Endereço"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="endereco[]" placeholder="Endereço"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
    </form>
```

Estou pegando ele via **serialize**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var form = $('form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index_server.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form,

            success: function(callback){

                console.log(callback);
            }
        });
    })
```

O problema é que com o **serialize** ele não envia corretamente para o PHP, dando um `print_r()` no PHP ele retorna:

```
Array
(
    [data] => 4731
    [telefone] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [endereco] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

    [nome] => 
)
```

Precisava que ele pegasse todos os dados do formulário corretamente. O problema está sendo somente esse que é um array e contém a propriedade `numero, operadora e contato`, ou seja, o **telefone**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Penso que o problema ta nos nomes dos inputs da form.

em vez de

```
telefone[0].numero etc..
```

tenta `telefone[0]['numero']`

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu